# Zod refine not trigger render on obejct

Tags: react-hook-form, zod

I am trying to create a constraint that the user must select at least one checkbox.
The problem is if the user clicks submit button without fulfilling this constraint and then select one of the checkbox - the error remains until clicking on submit again.

```
const schema = object({
  checkboxGroup: object({
    a: boolean(),
    b: boolean(),
  }).refine(
    ({ a, b }) => {
      return a || b;
    },
    {
      message: 'You must select at least one',
    },
  ),
});

export type SchemaType = TypeOf<typeof schema>;

export default function Foo() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<SchemaType>({
    resolver: zodResolver(schema),
  });

  return (
    <Box
      component="form"
      noValidate
      autoComplete="off"
      onSubmit={handleSubmit(() => {})}
    >
      <FormControl
        required
        error={!!errors.checkboxGroup}
        component="fieldset"
        variant="standard"
      >
        <FormLabel component="legend">CheckboxGroup</FormLabel>
        <FormGroup>
          <FormControlLabel
            control={<Checkbox />}
            {...register('checkboxGroup.a')}
            label="A"
          />
          <FormControlLabel
            control={<Checkbox />}
            {...register('checkboxGroup.b')}
            label="B"
          />
        </FormGroup>
        <FormHelperText error={!!errors.checkboxGroup}>
          {errors.checkboxGroup ? errors.checkboxGroup.message : ''}
        </FormHelperText>
      </FormControl>
      <Button variant="contained" type="submit">
        Save
      </Button>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

what you'll want to do is expose the [`clearErrors`](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/clearerrors) prop from the `useForm` hook to clear your errors.

For example, you could invoke the `clearErrors` on a change to your input field.

I'm not entirely sure what the `FormControlLabel`s are, but I am assuming those are containers for your checkboxes. Below code may not work as is, but you should get the idea on what to do.

```
export default function Foo() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    clearErrors,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<SchemaType>({
    resolver: zodResolver(schema),
  });

  return (
    <Box
      component="form"
      noValidate
      autoComplete="off"
      onSubmit={handleSubmit(() => {})}
    >
      <FormControl
        required
        error={!!errors.checkboxGroup}
        component="fieldset"
        variant="standard"
      >
        <FormLabel component="legend">CheckboxGroup</FormLabel>
        <FormGroup>
          <FormControlLabel
            control={<Checkbox onChange={() => clearErrors('a')} />}
            {...register('checkboxGroup.a')}
            label="A"
          />
          <FormControlLabel
            control={<Checkbox onChange={() => clearErrors('b')} />}
            {...register('checkboxGroup.b')}
            label="B"
          />
        </FormGroup>
        <FormHelperText error={!!errors.checkboxGroup}>
          {errors.checkboxGroup ? errors.checkboxGroup.message : ''}
        </FormHelperText>
      </FormControl>
      <Button variant="contained" type="submit">
        Save
      </Button>
    </Box>
  );
}
```